# Getting "Save Conflict, Your Change Conflicts..." while creating document set using CSOM C#

Tags: 2013, 2010, csom, document-set

I was working with creating document set in a folder in Document Library using `Client Side Object Model (C#)`. But strangely I got this error:

> Save Conflict. 
>    Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If
>    you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser,
>    refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.

The code which I used is:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
ContentTypeCollection listContentTypes = documentLibrary.ContentTypes;
clientContext.Load(listContentTypes, types => types.Include(type => type.Id, type => type.Name, type => type.Parent));
var result = clientContext.LoadQuery(listContentTypes.Where(c => c.Name == contentTypeName));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
ContentType targetDocumentSetContentType = result.FirstOrDefault();
ListItemCreationInformation newItemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
newItemInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
newItemInfo.LeafName = inventionDocumentSetName;
newItemInfo.FolderUrl = siteUrl + documentLibraryName + "/" + inventionFolderName;
ListItem newListItem = documentLibrary.AddItem(newItemInfo);
newListItem["ContentTypeId"] = targetDocumentSetContentType.Id.ToString();
newListItem.Update();
documentLibrary.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I have done a lot of research on this error but not found anything useful to avoid this.

When I run the same code on SharePoint 2010 it worked successfully but when I run the same code against SharePoint 2013 Environment it gives me this error.

Let me know if you need some more details to help then please comment it.

**PS:** I have already gone through [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184207/your-changes-conflict-with-those-made-concurrently-by-another-user) post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the Create and Update into two actions

```
ListItem newListItem = documentLibrary.AddItem(newItemInfo);
newListItem.Update();

//HERE GET THE ITEM BY ID AGAIN AND PERFORM UPDATE
newListItem = documentLibrary.GetItemById(ItemID);
clientContext.Load(newListItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


newListItem["ContentTypeId"] = targetDocumentSetContentType.Id.ToString();
newListItem.Update();
```

Comment: It worked for me on both the environment.